# swift error: Value of type 'AVAudioRecorder' has no member 'Delegate'

Tags: ios, swift

As a beginner, I am unable to figure out why I get this error. The code I am using comes directly from the Udacity course I am taking. Here is the code:

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation

class RecordSoundsViewController: UIViewController, <AVAudioRecorderDelegate> {

    var audioRecorder: AVAudioRecorder!

    @IBOutlet weak var recordingLabel: UILabel!

    @IBOutlet weak var recordbutton: UIButton!

    @IBOutlet weak var stopRecordingButton: UIButton!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        stopRecordingButton.isEnabled = false
    }

    @IBAction func recordAudio(_ sender: Any) {
        recordingLabel.text = "Recording in progress..."
        recordbutton.isEnabled = false
        stopRecordingButton.isEnabled = true

        let dirPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory,.userDomainMask, true)[0] as String
        let recordingName = "recordedVoice.wav"
        let pathArray = [dirPath, recordingName]
        let filePath = URL(string: pathArray.joined(separator: "/"))


        let session = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()
        try! session.setCategory(AVAudioSession.Category.playAndRecord, mode: AVAudioSession.Mode.default, options: AVAudioSession.CategoryOptions.defaultToSpeaker)

        try! audioRecorder = AVAudioRecorder(url: filePath!, settings: [:])
        audioRecorder.delegate = self
        audioRecorder.isMeteringEnabled = true
        audioRecorder.prepareToRecord()
        audioRecorder.record()    }

    @IBAction func stopRecording(_ sender: Any) {
        recordbutton.isEnabled = true
        stopRecordingButton.isEnabled = false
        recordingLabel.text = "Tap to Record"

        audioRecorder.stop()
        let audioSession = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()
        try! audioSession.setActive(false)
    }

    func audioRecorderDidFinishRecording(_ recorder: AVAudioRecorder, successfully flag: BOOL) {
        print("finished recording")
    }
}
```

I appreciate any help you cold give me. XCode 11.5, Swift 5.2
Thanks,
Mike

Comment: try instead of "class RecordSoundsViewController: UIViewController, <AVAudioRecorderDelegate>" this "class RecordSoundsViewController: UIViewController, AVAudioRecorderDelegate"

Comment: That's an interesting version of Xcode to be using 

Answer (score 0):

You should get a bunch of more errors.

Anyway this is **not** Objective-C. Adopting protocols is not in angle brackets

```
class RecordSoundsViewController: UIViewController, AVAudioRecorderDelegate {
```

and the boolean type in Swift is `Bool` (not `BOOL`)

```
func audioRecorderDidFinishRecording(_ recorder: AVAudioRecorder, successfully flag: Bool) {
```

And don't `try!`. Catch errors.